# Javascript + keep external events in events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Can anyone help me I'm a newbie.

I have set up external events that are droppable in my calender.

My calender holds my events when I'm clicking on next/previous. But when I reload my page the events are gone.

what It's wrong in my javascript?

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {
            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text())
                // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable(
            {
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
            });
        });

        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text())
            //  start: '2016-03-04'// use the element's text as the event title
        };

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            events: eventObject,

            // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar

            drop: function (date, allDay) {
                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var eventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, eventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                //   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchexternal-events' )  ;

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *when I reload my page the events are gone*: the JavaScript has no memory if you close or refresh the page, when you reload the page, the script has a new fresh start of execution.

Comment: need to store data somewhere ... send to server with ajax or use localStorage

Comment: thanks. Can you give me an example of the ajax / local storage function? I don't know what url I have to use when the events comes from the external events...